# Why can't I iterate using for loops in a async function called from an express route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a tinder clone. When calling the collection of users to swipe through I need to filter out any users that have already been liked or disliked by active user. I want to handle this on my backend. However when the function is called it never even begins to iterate. I've tried `for of`  loops and standard `for` loops however it does not run. Im using mongodb for my database.

```
function asyncHandler(callback) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

//Express route calling a get request

router.get("/user/match/:id", asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const currentUser = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

    console.log(currentUser._id);

    if ( currentUser.gender === "Male" && currentUser.sexualPreference === "Straight") {

      const user = await User.find({ gender: "Female", sexualPreference: "Straight",});

 //Passing the currentUser and user(s) into the filter function

      filter(currentUser, user);

    }
  })
);

//Filter function called

const filter = async (currentUser, user, req, res, error, next) => {
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentUser.likes; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < currentUser.dislikes; j++) {
        if (
          currentUser.likes !== user._id ||
          currentUser.dislikes !== user._id
        ) {
          return res.json({ user });
        } else {
          return res.json({ message: "There are no new people in your area" });
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};


//Current user object

    {
   "matches":[
      {
         "_id":60ede6d7d4eb858097ec9de8,
         "firstName":"Daenerys",
         "path":"uploads/1626203863396.jpg"
      },
      {
         "_id":60ede6a3d4eb858097ec9de7,
         "firstName":"Cersei",
         "path":"uploads/1626203811243.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "likes":[
      "60ede6d7d4eb858097ec9de8",
      "60ede6a3d4eb858097ec9de7"
   ],
   "dislikes":[
      "60ede703d4eb858097ec9de9"
   ],
   "_id":60ede684d4eb858097ec9de6,
   "firstName":"Jon",
   "lastName":"Snow",
   "emailAddress":"JonSnow@gmail.com",
   "gender":"Male",
   "sexualPreference":"Straight",
   "age":26,
   "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "path":"uploads/1626203780345.jpg",
   "__v":0
}

//Users array returned from get request

    [
  {
    matches: [ [Object] ],
    likes: [ '60ede684d4eb858097ec9de6' ],
    dislikes: [],
    _id: 60ede6a3d4eb858097ec9de7,
    firstName: 'Cersei',
    lastName: 'Lannister',
    emailAddress: 'Cersei@gmail.com',
    gender: 'Female',
    sexualPreference: 'Straight',
    age: 35,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    path: 'uploads/1626203811243.jpg',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    matches: [ [Object] ],
    likes: [ '60ede684d4eb858097ec9de6' ],
    dislikes: [],
    _id: 60ede6d7d4eb858097ec9de8,
    firstName: 'Daenerys',
    lastName: 'Targeryen',
    emailAddress: 'Daenerys@gmail.com',
    gender: 'Female',
    sexualPreference: 'Straight',
    age: 26,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    path: 'uploads/1626203863396.jpg',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    matches: [ [Object] ],
    likes: [ '60ede684d4eb858097ec9de6' ],
    dislikes: [],
    _id: 60ede703d4eb858097ec9de9,
    firstName: 'Brienne',
    lastName: 'of Tarth',
    emailAddress: 'Brienne@gmail.com',
    gender: 'Female',
    sexualPreference: 'Straight',
    age: 30,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    path: 'uploads/1626203907149.jpg',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: did you add any console.log to confirm that no loop occur ?

Comment: it would help if you could give us a small sample of what `currentUser` and `user` looks like.

Comment: I've added the user array and currentUser object

Answer (score 0):

When you call the filter function you only pass 2 variables

```
filter(currentUser, user);
```

and when you define it you have a lot more.

```
const filter = async (currentUser, user, req, res, error, next) => {
```

therefore, at least res is not defined.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately its not working. Appreciated though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
filter(currentUser, user, req, res)
```

and

```
const filter = async (currentUser, user, req, res) => {
```

Hope this solves the issue.

EDIT :

As per me, there are many errors in your code. First of all, you run a loop where you limit the loop to currentUser.likes which is an array and not a number. And also there is no use to run 2 loops. You can just do

```
for (let i = 0; i < (currentUser.likes.length + currentUser.dislikes.length); i++)
```

Next, user object is an array but you are not using it as an array. So, you can just do

```
if (currentUser.likes !== user[i]._id ||ncurrentUser.dislikes !== user[i]._id)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately its not working. Appreciated though :)

Comment: @RandyBeans I have updated the answer. Try it and let me know if it works. And also please upvote the answer if you find it helpful :D